# How is the method run(T var1, Environment var2) in Application class called in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, microservices, backend, dropwizard

Within a Dropwizard application,
the abstract run method in the Application class is usually overriden in the main service with something like this:

```
@Override
public void run(MyServiceConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    // application logic
}
```

I tried tracing the execution logic and couldn't figure out where/how that method is being called. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning, when you run your [Dropwizard application as a server](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#running-your-application) you're giving the `server` command on the command line interface (CLI).
The example the documentation gives is:

> java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml

In `io.dropwizard.Application` (which you normally extend) we can see that the following commands are added to the `bootstrap`:

```java
protected void addDefaultCommands(Bootstrap<T> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addCommand(new ServerCommand<>(this));
    bootstrap.addCommand(new CheckCommand<>(this));
}
```

In this case `this` is the instance of your class extending `Application`, which is given to the `ServerCommand`.

Then the `run` method in the same class will parse the CLI:

```java
public void run(String... arguments) throws Exception {
    final Bootstrap<T> bootstrap = new Bootstrap<>(this);
    addDefaultCommands(bootstrap);
    initialize(bootstrap);
    // Should be called after initialize to give an opportunity to set a custom metric registry
    bootstrap.registerMetrics();

    final Cli cli = new Cli(new JarLocation(getClass()), bootstrap, System.out, System.err);
    // only exit if there's an error running the command
    cli.run(arguments).ifPresent(this::onFatalError);
}
```

When we follow  `cli.run(arguments).ifPresent(this::onFatalError);` we end up in `io.dropwizard.cli.Cli#run`. In this method the command is parsed, and since we specified `server` it will find that command by name and execute it:

```java
public Optional<Throwable> run(String... arguments) {
...
final Namespace namespace = parser.parseArgs(arguments);
final Command command = requireNonNull(commands.get(namespace.getString(COMMAND_NAME_ATTR)),
    "Command is not found");
try {
    command.run(bootstrap, namespace);
...
```

The server command will be an instance of `io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand`, which extends `io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand`.

And it is in the `EnvironmentCommand` that we can see that your requested `Application.run(...)` method is executed:

```java
protected void run(Bootstrap<T> bootstrap, Namespace namespace, T configuration) throws Exception {
    ...

    bootstrap.run(configuration, environment);
    application.run(configuration, environment);
    run(environment, namespace, configuration);
}
```

This line specifically:

> application.run(configuration, environment);

The `T configuration` is added via the base class of `EnvironmentCommand`, which is `io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand`.

All code is taken from Dropwizard version `2.1.0`

Comment: Wow! I only went as far as the Cli run() method. Had I followed one more step, the answer would've been right there. Talk about giving up before striking gold. Thank you so much, it was very easy to follow!

Comment: @slindenau Can you please look at the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74286744/getting-the-following-error-in-dropwizard-version-2-0-19