# Getting the following error in dropwizard version 2.0.19

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am getting the following error in dropwizard version 2.0.19:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory.configure(DefaultLoggingFactory.java:170)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:94)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
    at com.helloWorld.main(HelloWorldApplication.java:100)
```

The DefaultLoggingFactory comes only from dropwizard-logging 2.0.19 and there are no conflicting versions for the same.
Can somebody help in pointing out the issue?

I tried checking for conflicting versions but none were present

Comment: Are you using a custom logging implementation that you've added to your project? I can find a similar error in `loggly`: https://github.com/reines/dropwizard-logging-loggly/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

I was using a custom logging implementation in my project. Upgrading it from LoggingFilter to LoggingFeature solved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).